# Django-tagging 2 tag field in same model

Tags: python, django, tags, django-tagging

I'm using django-tagging. It works fine when I want 1 tag collection for the model. But now i need to use 2 different collections, somehow like this:

```
class Compare(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    left_tags  = TagField()
    right_tags = TagField()
```

Is it possible with tagging? I hope somebody has an example and will share it! Thanks! :)

Comment: Yes that's possible. Are you having any particular problem with that approach?

Answer (score 2):

does TagField take a optional `related_name` attribute you could use?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

I've never used this app myself, but thats the django-ish way of solving this.

Comment: related_name is not working with this field. It looks like not supperted yet. There is a issue about it here: http://code.google.com/p/django-tagging/issues/detail?id=115&q=multiple. And a "hack" solution for handling it.